# In Dancer2, what is the preferred way to keep an instance of a service-like object, that a module's routes methods can access?

Tags: perl, dependency-injection, dancer2

Imagine something along the lines of:

```
get( => 'hello' => sub ($app) {
    my $hello_service = $app->get_instance_of('hello_service');
    my $message = $hello_service->greet('world');
    template 'hello', {message => $message};
});
```

hello_service it a bit complex to initialize, I would not want to have to new it up on every request. I also don't want it to store it in package variable. Is there something in Dancer2 or some other trick that could allow me injecting services like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to initialize my service style classes with [Bread::Board](https://metacpan.org/pod/Bread::Board) then expose them globally through a namespace like `MyApp::Service`, something like:

```perl
package MyApp::Service;

use Bread::Board;

# Generate service depdencencies with Bread::Board
my $c = container 'MyApp' => as {
    container 'Service' => as {
        service 'hello_service' => (
            lifecycle => 'Singleton',
            block     => sub {
                require MyApp::Service::HelloService;
                my $s = shift; # Use $s to resolve dependencies
                return MyApp::Service::HelloService->new; # Do args and stuff here
            }
        );
    };
};

no Bread::Board;

# Retrieve via MyApp::Service::hello_service
sub hello_service { return $c->resolve('Service/hello_service') }
```

There may be another way to do this, but this is the way I've always done it for `Mojolicious`, `Dancer`, etc. I know you mentioned not wanting to do it in a package variable (sorry).

Comment: So, in my 'get' coderef, I'd call MyApp::Service::hello_service()->greet('world'), right?

Comment: @Jan Yeah `MyApp::Service->hello_service->greet('world');` should do, there are some really cool DI things you can do with `Bread::Board` too so make sure you read up on it.