# Central constructor, share data bless hash between packages

Tags: perl, oop

```
package Father;

sub new {
  my $class   = shift;

  return bless {}, $class;
}

1;

package Uncle;

use parent qw(Father);

sub status {
  my $self   = shift;

  $self->{news} = 'bad';

  return $self;
}

1;

package Son;

use parent qw(Father);

sub set {
  my $self   = shift;

  $self->{news} = 'good';

  return $self;

}

1;
```

program.pl

```
use Uncle;

use Son;

my $self = Uncle->new()->status;

print Dumper($self);

$self = Son->new()->set;

print Dumper($self);

$self = Uncle->new()->status;

print Dumper($self);
```

Print result:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'news' => 'bad'
               }, 'Uncle' );

$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'news' => 'good'
               }, 'Son' );

$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'news' => 'bad'
               }, 'Uncle' );
```

Here in last Uncle should be **good** because I set that in Son package

I found a solution with rebless, also another with:

```
package Father;

my $store_data = { };

sub new {
  my $class   = shift;

  return bless { data => $store_data }, $class;
}

1;

package Uncle;
...

$self->{data}->{news} = 'bad';

package Son;
...

$self->{data}->{news} = 'good';
```

but can be done this without create another variable **$store_data** ?

**Update:**
In the constructor, I call external packages so I assigned the result to the hash reference, inside child package I need that data and others config values, some times I set value to undef key hash (constructor hash) reference from one child and in other child check if exists $self->{the_key}

Here a full working example, but I need to create variable and I have to call $self->{data}->{key} I want to avoid that.

```
package Father;

my $store_data = { };

sub new {
  my $class   = shift;

  return bless { data => $store_data }, $class;
}

1;

package Uncle;

use parent qw(Father);

sub status {
  my $self   = shift;

  $self->{data}->{news} = 'bad';

  return $self;
}

sub other {
  my $self   = shift;

  return $self;
}

1;

package Son;

use parent qw(Father);

sub set {
  my $self   = shift;

  $self->{data}->{news} = 'good';

  return $self;

}

1;


use Uncle;
use Son;

my $self = Uncle->new()->status;
print Dumper($self);
$self = Son->new()->set;
print Dumper($self);
$self = Uncle->new()->other;
print Dumper($self);


$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'data' => {
                             'news' => 'bad'
                           }
               }, 'Uncle' );
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'data' => {
                             'news' => 'good'
                           }
               }, 'Son' );
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'data' => {
                             'news' => 'good'
                           }
               }, 'Uncle' );
```

Comment: What? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, since when are sons fathers. I'm a son and I'm not a father. Same goes for uncles.

Comment: Hi there @ikegami. thank you for your input. I want to have access the latest data of parent constructor in all childs packages, my case is something related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75899500/in-dancer2-what-is-the-preferred-way-to-keep-an-instance-of-a-service-like-obje   Not need Moose

Comment: The child update different type of data, in the end the data constructor of parent should be reflect the updated data of childs packages

Comment: So you expect that when you set data in a child's object that data in an object of _another_ class changes as well, because they are both derived from the same parent? Why do you expect that?  If that were the case then the two derived classes would not be at all independent, right?  Changing one would change the other.  Imaging I have `Car` and `Truck` classes derived from a `Vehicle` class, and I set an attribute (data) `speed` for a `Car`'s object and ... the `speed` attribute of a `Truck`'s object changes? What would be the use of having separate classes (`Car` and `Truck`) then?

Comment: Hi, I made a update

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying you want a single variable you can access everywhere? So use a single variable! Subs would be best to give access to that variable.

```perl
# Separate get and set accessors.
my $news;
sub set_news { $news = $_[0]; }
sub get_news { $news }
```

or

```perl
# Common accessors for getting and setting.
my $news;
sub news { $news = $_[0] if @_; $news }
```

(Add a `shift;` if you want to call them as methods.)